# How to send a file from any source to an endpoint through a request in NestJS?

Tags: javascript, file, request, microservices, nestjs

I have a microservice architecture, and I need to create a service which will receive a file in csv format through a request. I'm using NestJS and up until now most of my requests have been really simple, just receiving strings. So far googling the only solution I've seen is using third party software like Multer which isn't really good for my case as it's geared towards sending form data, and I'm not using a form, nor sending anything, just receiving. Basically I just need to receive a file through the request and access the information inside of it. As this is a microservice architecture, I need this to be independent from the source of the file. Can anyone point me in the right way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide an example of why you can't use a form ?

Comment: Because I'm creating an endpoint that should be accessible to any other service that is created in the future via a request, i'm not allowed to force someone to manually fill up a form to access my service

Comment: A form can be created and sended by another service (machine)